# Tooltip/title for original creator of Community Wiki posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

When reading questions and answers I like the ability to glance at a users reputation to give an indication of how much they're trusted / how likely they are to know "how the site works".  This also applies to comments - I can hover over these to see the tooltop of rep.

It doesn't apply to users of CW marked posts though - is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

A community wiki post does not *belong* to a single user.  The post as you see it may have been edited by several people.

Showing the details of the original poster wouldn't be of any benefit.

Comment: I understand that, but by that argument the original poster should just be buried in the revision history.  If you're displaying a user name, why not display the rep in a tooltip in the same way it is elsewhere?